# How to access JSON this atribute using cytoscape.js and qtip?

Tags: jquery, json, qtip2

I'm trying to access a JSON atribute using cytoscape/qtip. Actually I got the following

```
  <script>
$(function(){
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById('cy'),
ready: function(){
},
layout: {
    name: 'circle',
    padding: 10
  },
style: [
{

selector: 'node',
css: {
'content': 'data(name)'
}
},
{
selector: 'edge',
css: {
'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
}
}
],
elements: {
nodes: [
{ data: { id: 'j', name: 'Jerry' } },
{ data: { id: 'e', name: 'Elaine' } },
{ data: { id: 'g', name: 'George' } }
],
edges: [
{ data: { source: 'j', target: 'e' } },
{ data: { source: 'g', target: 'j' } }
]
},
});

  cy.elements().qtip({
content: function(){ return this.id();  },
position: {
my: 'top center',
at: 'bottom center'
},
style: {
classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
tip: {
width: 16,
height: 8
}
}
});

});
</script>
```

When I run this I access the id JSON atribute. It simply shows a graph structure at the screen and when I click on the j node it shows j using qtip and this for each one of the nodes. But what I want to show is **the name for each of the nodes when I click on each one instead of its id**. I've tried to replace this.id() by this.name() but it does not work. I'm not so familiarized with jquery.

thanks for your atention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`content: function(){ return this.attr('name');  },`